# How to make the Publish button follow the page in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, button, publish

I want to make the publish button follow the page (floating/sticky). Is there any way?
Thanks,
The Anh

Comment: Your question is really vague. Can you explain what you want, and what you have tried? How do you want it to work? We need more information. **Edit** your question to clarify.

Comment: Hi janw, I just need to save time when click Publish/Update button when writing post in admin. I dont want to scroll back to top of the page each time I want to click the button. Hope you can understand my needs. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to make the div element of the Publish or Update button stick to the page.

To make a div element stick to the page you can use some solutions:

1. CSS: Make the div of the button have position fixed property

> `#submitdiv {position: fixed; z-index:999999}`

1. jQuery solution: use a jquery sticky plugin (http://stickyjs.com, http://someweblog.com/hcsticky-jquery-floating-sticky-plugin/). Then implement some it to #submitdiv element

Stickyjs:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#sticker").sticky({topSpacing:0});});
```

hcSticky:

```
$("#submitdiv").css('z-index','999999').hcSticky({noContainer:true});
```

1. Use a wordpress plugin. I know a plugin that can help you: http://wordpress.org/plugins/floating-publish-button/. Please take a look.

Hope this answer can help you.

Comment: Oh..! your answer is very helpful. that's all my needs. thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Since WordPress version 4.1, this is built in feature. The whole right side widget area, including "Publish" widget, is float with page.

Comment: The following bug, however can cause the publish widget's stickiness to not turn on: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/37790 (Specifically, this happens on the post editor if the main editor is not long, but there are instead long (or many) metabox fields  (e.g. ACF fields).

Answer (score -1):

I always try to do things without plugins so I've researched a bit... And let me add this: sondoha reply is ok with sticky if you don't have a big post/page with a lot of fields, otherwise it will stick to a maximum height regarding all the sidebar panels. So that, for me wasn't enough.

I've managed to use only CSS:

```
function baannng_floating_publish() {
    echo '<style>
        #poststuff #post-body.columns-2 #side-sortables { margin-top: 330px; }
        #submitdiv { position: fixed; margin-top: -330px; right: 20px; z-index: 9999; max-width: 278px; width: 100%; -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3););}
    </style>';
}
add_action('admin_head', 'baannng_floating_publish');
```

I've added some shadows just be visually comfortable when overlapping other panels.
Add the previous code to a function field inside your theme if any available, or to functions.php.

Regards,
H.

Comment: I've edited the #submitdiv from 'top' to 'margin-top' and pixels to be adjusted to any message bar published/updated info.